# Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'user_id' at row 1

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to insert into my SQL database. For some reason I'm getting the `Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'user_id' at row 1` error.

Here's my table schema:

[image]
As you can see, `user_id` is a foreign key that references a column from another table. I'm not sure if you need that information but yeah. I'm getting the error from my insert php.

Here's my insert php:

```js
<?php
require_once ('database.php');

if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$fromdate = ($_POST['fromdate']);
$todate = ($_POST['todate']);
$reason = ($_POST['reason']);
$status = ($_POST['status']);

{
$database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO leaves (user_id, full_name, phone, email, fromdate, todate, reason, status)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$insert = $database->prepare($insert_query);
$insert->execute(array($user_id, $full_name, $phone, $email, $fromdate, $todate, $reason, $status));

echo "<script>alert('Successfully sent!'); window.location='leaveform.php'</script>";
}
}
?>
```

Form:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="form__name" style="font-family: Questrial; ">
            Leave Application Form
        </div>
        <div class="time__container">
            <div class="section">
                <div class="box">
                    1
                </div><span>Date</span>
            </div>
            <form action="insert-leave.php" class="form__time" method="post">
                <div class="date">
                    <label for="date">From</label> <input id="date" type="date" name="fromdate" required>
                </div>
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
                <div class="date">
                    <label for="date">To</label> <input id="date" type="date" name="todate" required>
                </div>
                <div class="timezone">
                    <label for="timezone"></label> 
                        </select>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="message__container">
            <div class="section">
                <div class="box">
     2
                  
                </div><span>Reason</span>
            </div>
            <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="reason" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="contact__container">
            <div class="section">
                <div class="box">
     3
                    
                </div><span>Contact Information</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form__contact">
                <div class="cname">
                    <label for="cname">Name</label> <input name="full_name" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $fullname; ?>" required>
                </div>
                <div class="cnum">
                    <label for="cnum">Phone Number</label> <input id="cnum" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="phone" value="<?php echo $contact; ?>" required>
                </div>
                <div class="email">
                    <label for="cemail">Email</label> <input id="cemail" name="email" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" required>
                </div>
    <div class="email">
                    <label for="cemail"></label> <input type="hidden" name="status" required>
                </div>
    <div class="id">
                    <label for="id"></label> <input type="hidden" name="user_id" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Looks like `$_POST['user_id'];` is empty. Please check

Comment: Have you confirmed that `$_POST` contains the keys you're querying?

Comment: @Jens I'm not sure if I know what you mean sorry.

Comment: @MTCoster I'm not sure really, how do you do that? Sorry I'm new to mysql.

Comment: print_r($_POST) to see if user_id coming after form submission has any value.

Comment: @JohnZ can you please Show the form where you send the values from

Comment: @Jens Added the form

Comment: @Jens actually nvm I fixed it, my bad

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="user_id" required> clearly shows you will not have user_id in $_POST. If you are probably using sessions then you can put <input type="hidden" name="user_id" required value="<?php echo $_SESSION[USER_ID_VAR]; ?>"> which will put the ID of logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

You never set a value to `user_id`

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" required>
```

so  `$_POST['user_id'];` is blank

Answer (score 0):

Added

```html
<div class="id">
  <label for="id"></label> <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?
  php echo $user_id; ?>" name="user_id" required>
 </div>
```